# Issue in Parse XML in ionic 3 using TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

My code is always printing error log, how can i find the exception please tell me the right way to this
Here is my code

```
this.http.get('http://www.gazetaexpress.com/rss/sport/?xml=1').subscribe(data => {
    this.xmlItems = data;
    console.log("data:"+data);
    xml2js.parseString(this.xmlItems, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: did you access this URL in browser. its returning error?

Comment: you need to give the error, plus more of the code

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya url working perfect in browser. please share working code if you have done this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you have is not with parsing XML here, but in how you access the URL from within ionic/angular app.

I simplified the code example you have to this:

```
this.http.get('http://www.gazetaexpress.com/rss/sport/?xml=1').subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Now added it as a method to ionViewDidLoad in this stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4qbega

The error you are getting based on this context is this one:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null…}
error: ProgressEvent
headers: HttpHeaders
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: null
__proto__: HttpErrorResponse
```

So to fix just data intake you need to do the following:

- use https URL
- also use responseType: 'text'

Code:

```
this.http.get('https://www.gazetaexpress.com/rss/sport/?xml=1', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Now to make this work with your code, it should be something like this:

```
this.http.get('https://www.gazetaexpress.com/rss/sport/?xml=1', { responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => {
    this.xmlItems = data;
    console.log("data:"+data);
    xml2js.parseString(this.xmlItems, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

PS: also check this good article here in case you have more q: https://www.ionicrun.com/transform-xml-to-json-in-ionic-2-with-angular-4-3/

Comment: thanks a lot data is printing now but result showing 
[object object] on line console.log(result);

Comment: I can check it out tomorrow, what version of xml2js are you using

Comment: Your code works i just added {responseType: 'text'}) these lines in my code and its working perfect now.
Thank u so much Sergey Rudenko for your support, hopefully we keep in touch in future :)

Comment: No problem;) glad to help